# Como atualizar a RecyclerView de forma simples e eficiente?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Das formas que conheço para atualizar uma RecyclerView a mais eficiente é recorrer aos métodos do adapter

- notifyItemMoved
- notifyItemRangeChanged
- notifyItemRangeInserted
- notifyItemRangeRemoved

Eles, ao contrário de `notifyDataSetChanged()`, apenas provocam o *refresh* dos itens visíveis a que se referem(aqueles que foram movidos/alterados/inseridos/removidos), sendo, por isso, mais eficiente.

O seu uso é simples quando as alterações são feitas "à vez", basta chamar o método correspondente à alteração feita.
A dificuldade surge quando várias alterações são feitas de uma só vez, por exemplo, quando se recebe uma nova lista, actualizada, proveniente de uma chamada a um serviço, o que me leva a utilizar `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Neste último caso, como posso fazer a atualização recorrendo aos métodos `notifyItemXXX()`?

Answer (score 5):

Na revisão 24.2.0 da Support Library, uma das [actualizações](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-api-updates) foi a adição da classe [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html).
Ela possibilita calcular a diferença entre duas colecções e obter um objecto do tipo [DiffUtil.DiffResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.DiffResult.html) que contém uma lista de operações de actualização para serem aplicadas a um RecyclerView.Adapter.

As operações são aplicadas recorrendo ao método [DiffResult#dispatchUpdatesTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.DiffResult.html#dispatchUpdatesTo(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)) que internamente usa os métodos `notifyItemXXX()` para notificar o *adapter*.

```
DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback); 
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
```

DiffUtil precisa obter algumas informações sobre a colecção antiga e nova, como o tamanho e como comparar itens. Essas informações são obtidas usando o [DiffUtil.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.Callback.html) passado ao método [DiffUtil.calculateDiff()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html#calculateDiff(android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil.Callback)).
A implementação do *callback* depende do tipo que a colecção guarda.

Exemplo de implementação:

```
public class ProdutoDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback{

    List<Produto> oldProdutos;
    List<Produto> newProdutos;

    public ProdutoDiffCallback(List<Produto> newProdutos, List<Produto> oldProdutos) {
        this.newProdutos = newProdutos;
        this.oldProdutos = oldProdutos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldProdutos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newProdutos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldProdutos.get(oldItemPosition).id == newProdutos.get(newItemPosition).id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldProdutos.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newProdutos.get(newItemPosition));
    }

}
```

A actualização do RecyclerView pode ser implementada, num método do Adapter, da seguinte forma:

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<Produto> newProdutos) {
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new ProdutoDiffCallback(this.Produtos, newProduto));
    this.Produtos = newProdutos
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```