# O que é o RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Eu vi a classe na [documentação do Andorid](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView), mas não entendi bem sua funcionalidade, onde esse objeto deve ser usado e com qual objetivo. O nome me remeteu a algo que não parece ser o que de fato ele representa.

Tem alguma coisa em outras plataformas que se comporte de forma semelhante para eu tentar enxergar melhor?

Comment: Link útil: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: Estou convencido que já vi uma pergunta identica por aí, mas não consigo encontrar. De qualquer forma acho a pergunta bem relevante

Comment: Não achei, mas se tiver dupa aí ;)

Comment: Pra mim o nome é bem aplicável. `Recycle` de `Reciclar`, que é o que ele faz com as `views`. Ele reusa as células.

Comment: Acho esse link bem interessante: https://imasters.com.br/android/listas-com-recyclerview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A RecyclerView é uma *view* que permite exibir uma parte de um conjunto grande de dados.

Ela recorre a várias [classes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#nested-classes), nomeadamente à [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter), [RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) e [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator).

A função do RecyclerView.Adapter é "pegar" os dados, provenientes de uma fonte de dados qualquer, e "transformá-los" nas *views* a serem exibidas pela RecyclerView.

Gerir a forma/disposição em como esse conjunto de *views* é exibido é da responsabilidade do RecyclerView.LayoutManager.

O ItemAnimator permite animar os itens quando esses são movimentados.

O delegar dessas responsabilidade permite à RecyclerView exibir um mesmo conjunto de dados de formas diferentes. Não só como cada dado(campo) do item é exibido, como também a disposição de cada item no seu conjunto: lista vertical ou horizontal, grelha uniforme ou *stggered*, ou em outra forma qualquer.

Julgo que o nome se deve ao facto da implementação do RecyclerView.Adapter forçar que *views* não mais usadas sejam reaproveitadas quando necessário.
Isso é conseguido com os métodos `onCreateViewHolder()` e `onBindViewHolder()`.

- Quando é necessário um novo conjunto de *views*, o método `onCreateViewHolder()` é chamado seguido de `onBindViewHolder()`.
- Caso existam *views* disponíveis, apenas é chamado o método `onBindViewHolder()`.

Por outro lado ela obriga a implementação do "Padrão View Holder", onde um objecto [RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder) é usado para "guardar" as referências às *views*, evitando o uso repetido do método `findViewById()`.

Note que tanto ListView como GridView possibilitam o reaproveitamento de *views* e a implementação do "Padrão View Holder", no entanto a sua implementação é facultativa.

Em várias publicação tenho visto ela ser apresentada como um substituto da ListView. Na minha opinião é mais do que isso: é uma nova abordagem, mais flexível, estruturada e com maior performance, de exibir uma vista limitada de um grande conjunto de dados.

- Flexível, porque recorre a objectos externos personalizáveis.
- Estruturada, porque explicitamente obriga ao reaproveitamento das *views* e à implementação do Padrão View Holder.
- Performance, além do reaproveitamento das *views* e padrão View Holder, permite a [actualização selectiva de itens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178108/2541), evitando que todo o conjunto de dados antigo seja substituído pelo novo conjunto de dados. Apenas os itens modificados/apagados/inseridos são actualizados.

Eu uso a RecyclerView quando quero tirar partido do que ela oferece de diferente: performance, layout e animações à medida. Em casos "mais simples", com poucos dados e não sujeitos a alterações, uso a ListView ou GridView, mas sempre implemento o padrão ViewHolder.

Como complemento ver:

- [Qual é a diferença entre ListView e RecyclerView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160018/2541)
- [Qual é o propósito da classe RecyclerView.Adapter ao utilizar o RecyclerView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238143/2541)
- [Como atualizar a RecyclerView de forma simples e eficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178108/2541)

> Tem alguma coisa em outras plataformas que se comporte de forma semelhante para eu tentar enxergar melhor?

- iOS

  [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview?language=objc).
- WPF/UWP

  Qualquer [ItemsControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-pt/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.1) que use um [VirtualizingStackPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-pt/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel?view=netframework-4.7.1) com `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` para exibir os itens.